# undefinded value added to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have coded a array reverse function

which should returns like the standard `reverse()` method a new reversed array.

```
function reverseArray(array){

    let new_array = [];
    for (let i = array[array.length-1]; i >= 0; i --) {

        new_array.push(array[i]);
        console.log(typeof new_array[i]);
    }
    return new_array;
}
```

the output differs from the expected outcome

```
let my_array = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(reverseArray(my_array));
// -> [ undefined, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

the first inserted value is of type `undefined` which I can not understand why

the outcome of `console.log(typeof new_array[i]);`  to trace what type the inserted values have gave me

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
number
number
undefined
```

which confuses me even more

Comment: `let i = array[array.length-1];` sets i to 5 - i.e the value in the last element ... if the array was `[1,2,3,4,1000]` you'd end up with a lot more undefineds... you want `let i = array.length-1;` - having said that ... array's already have a reverse method - is there a particular reason you're writing one yourself?

Comment: .as an exercise

Comment: also, you're console.logging position 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ... while the array is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 length - so, of course you'll get stupid results :p

Comment: And `console.log(typeof new_array[i]);` is useless, because you are iterating array in backward direction, so for example on i=4 (in the start), there will be only one element in new_array, so asking for `new_array[4]` is totally useless. Of course it returns `undefined`

Comment: cool, exercises are a good way to learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the length of the array, not the last element.

```
for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

For getting the type of the item, you need to take the last index, not the index of the original array. For example at beginn, you have `i = 4`, but in the reversed array, the value at this index is `undefined`, because the length is one. And so on.

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
    let new_array = [];
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        new_array.push(array[i]);
    }
    return new_array;
}

let my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(reverseArray(my_array));
```